# Spring Cloud Starter Eureka without a webserver

Tags: java, spring, webserver, netflix-eureka

Is it possible to run an eureka client without running a webserver? The *'spring-cloud-starter-eureka'* artifact automatically pulls in *'spring-boot-starter-web'*. Why is that? Is it possible to run the client without actually starting up a webserver?

My problem is that starting up a webserver eats up around ~200mb of ram. This is a problem because the memory allocated for the apps I want to use eureka with is ranging from 256-512mb.

Comment: If it isn't a web app, then how are you going to receive calls to your service? Eureka is for rest based services, to register you would at least require the web related stuff from spring (you can try excluding tomcat). But then what? You cannot use any other functionality as the default support if for Rest based services...

Comment: These apps are small crawlers. They don't receive calls, only make to other services. (Query/call other services for next sites to crawl and send data with the crawled information for saving to other services.)

Comment: Then try excluding the `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` as a dependency.

Comment: I had the same idea but is there any side-effects for doing that?

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea... To be able to use Eureka you need to be registered, it might be that your service gets yanked as it cannot respond to messages from Eureka. But as stated I have no idea...

Answer (score 4):

It seems you don't need this service of yours to serve web request but still need the it to access your eureka server.

So disable web from the application.

```
spring.main.web-environment=false
```

And use the Discoveryclient to fetch the services.

If that is not good enough then remove eureka dependency and Make a rest call using (RestTemplate) to your eureka server to query for the services you need. Eureka exposes a rest endpoint for this. So it can't be used by even non-java/jvm based applications.

You could take a look at [this](https://github.com/awwal/spring-cloud-rest-client%22this) project I wrote some time ago to see how to do this.

If that is not good enough still. Then you might have to write plain java code which you should be writing in the first place unless you have a reason to be using a framework such as spring (Transaction,JPA, web, security etc).

Comment: Sounds great! Thanks! I'll award you the bounty in 13 hours. :)